# Whether mongodb deriver provide monitoring API for client to monitor the mongodb instance?

Tags: mongodb

I want to implement a HeartBeat connection check on the mongodb client side to check the MongoDB instance is online or not. I wander whether mongodb driver provides such functionality. I read this article http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/management/sdam-monitoring/ about topology monitoring but it only works for replicaset instance. I am looking for a general way to check any type of mongodb instance.